# goconst warnings from linter

Tags: go, linter

I'm using Atom to develop my Go app. The Linter in Atom is reporting an odd warning, and I don't see how it's a problem. Should I forever ignore the warning, or is there an alternate method I can implement?

**Error:** `Warning goconst 3 other occurrence(s) of "GET" found in: routes_pages.go:384:8 routes_pages.go:443:7 routes_pages.go:536:7 (goconst)    198:8`

**Details:**

I have routes in a file "app.go":

```
a.Router.HandleFunc("/login", a.PageLogin)
a.Router.HandleFunc("/register", a.PageRegister)
a.Router.HandleFunc("/event/add", a.PageEventCreate)
```

In a "routes_pages.go" file, I have func's defined like so:

```
func (a *App) PageEventCreate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    switch r.Method {
        case "GET":
            // Serve the resource.
        case "POST":
            // Create a new record.
        case "PUT":
            // Update an existing record.
        case "DELETE":
            // Remove the record.
        default:
            // Give an error message.
    }

}



func (a *App) PageLogin(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        switch r.Method {
            case "GET":
                // Serve the resource.
            case "POST":
                // Create a new record.
            case "PUT":
                // Update an existing record.
            case "DELETE":
                // Remove the record.
            default:
                // Give an error message.
        }

}
```

I have a multitude of func's setup this way. It makes it easy to work on any case (GET, POST, etc) in one place.

The Linter in Atom has a problem with this. It's reporting a warning for each item, for example:

```
Warning goconst 3 other occurrence(s) of "GET" found in: routes_pages.go:384:8 routes_pages.go:443:7 routes_pages.go:536:7 (goconst)    198:8
```

This warning occurs many times; once for every instance of switch/case with GET, PUT, DELETE, etc; ultimately, for me it's a huge list (thus a huge error list).

I see no apparent way to 'ignore' the warning in Atom, so I feel like just disabling the linter, which is not great for more serious warnings...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a warning that you're re-using the same string literal in multiple places.  This can be problematic because string literals are liable to be misspelled without noticing.  The solution is to use a constant instead.  This is made very easy in your case, because all of the (standard) HTTP verbs are already constants exported by the `http` package.  Just update your string literals to use the contant version instead:

```
func (a *App) PageLogin(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        switch r.Method {
            case http.MethodGet:
                // Serve the resource.
            case http.MethodPost:
                // Create a new record.
            case http.MethodPut:
                // Update an existing record.
            case http.MethodDelete:
                // Remove the record.
            default:
                // Give an error message.
        }
}
```

By using a constant, you safeguard against an accidental typo.  Example:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("DLETE", ...)
```

would not result in a compile-time error (and may not even result in a runtime error, depending on the rest of your program's logic), but

```
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodDlete, ...)
```

will fail to compile.